# How we Read a .doc and .doxc file using PHP?

Tags: php, yii, document, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions

****I have a Document having Some Header, paragraph, and other sections.
I want to get these all information without losing style because I have to create a JSON array by using this data in key pair and show it into text boxes to edit this information.
Please help if someone do the same things :(
I'm have tried the [PHP WORD](http://%20https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/) extension
But I can't find the particular method the get the text, header or paragraph, etc.
Thanks :(**

Comment: PHP WORD extension => https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/

Comment: PHPWord functions are described [here](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html#basic-example). Docx is a [ZIP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) -file with [XML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) structures inside following the [WordML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/structure-of-a-wordprocessingml-document) standard. The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-doc/ccd7b486-7881-484c-a137-51170af7cc22) extention is binary and harder to parse.

Comment: @Code4R7 Looks like you have not read my question. I'm looking to read data from Docx file not write.